# Multiple session IDs in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, session-cookies, sessionid

I have set up session handling in Asp.Net Core according to documentation:

```ml
services.AddSession()
app.UseSession()
```

I also ensure that the session is not empty with the first request to the backend

```ml
    member __.Index() =
        __.HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Default", 42);
        let path = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "index.html")
        if File.Exists(path) then
            FileContentResult(File.ReadAllBytes(path), "text/html") :> ActionResult
        else
            ContentResult() :> ActionResult
```

Still, when I call WebApis on the backend from same browser app, I get 2 session IDs instead of a single session ID.

The only reason I could imagine is because I have multiple WebApis called immediately when the WebApp is loaded and all those APIs are async.

Could that explain the observation of multiple session IDs?
How could this be avoided?
Can I/should I set the session cookie/ID in the WebApp?

Comment: The Session uses a cookie to track and identify requests from a single browser. Please check your browser whether it disable cookie or not? Besides, have you ever overridden cookie session defaults use SessionOptions? Can you share the related code in the ConfigureServices method?

Comment: browser settings seem to be ok. the session is created and i have proper session ID for subsequent requests - it is just that the first requests cause 2 sessions/session IDs to be created. i do not override the session defaults - in ConfugreServices() i just configure the session with defaults as shown in the post. thx